# Shopify trailing comma behaving strange

Tags: javascript, json, shopify, liquid

I had some vanilla js that looked like this

```js
const products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 't-shirt'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 't-shirt'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'jeans'
    }
  ]
```

And I wanted to have these products linked if they had the same title. So I did it like this:

```js
products.forEach(product => {
    product.linked_products = 
      products
        .filter(linked_product => linked_product.id !== product.id && linked_product.title === product.title)
  })
```

This worked the way it was supposed to. But the implementation was wrong and I had to create a small json api in shopify. I tried to achieve the above code block in just liquid in a json format and the `if statement` is causing the output to sometimes have and sometimes not have a trailing comma which breaks. When I fetch the endpoint I get an error about unexpected tokens because there are trailing commas.

I isolated this down to the if statement causes the trailing comma to not work and I am struggling how to fix this. my code looks like this

```js
{% layout none %}

{
  "title": {{ collection.title | json }},
  "description": {{ collection.description | json }},
  "products": [
    {% for product in collection.products %}
      {
        "title": {{ product.title | json }},
        "linked_products": [
          {% for linked_product in collection.products %}
            {% if linked_product.id != product.id and linked_product.title == product.title %}
              {
                "title": {{ linked_product.title | json }},
                "handle": {{ linked_product.handle | json }}
              }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        ]
      }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless%}
    {% endfor%}
  ]
}
```

The output I get is looking like this

```js
{
  "title": "Leggings",
  "description": "",
  "products": [
      {
        "title": "High waisted leggings",
        "linked_products": [
              {
                "title": "High waisted leggings",
                "handle": "high-waisted-leggings-1"
              },
            
              {
                "title": "High waisted leggings",
                "handle": "high-waisted-leggings"
              }
        ]
      },
    
      {
        "title": "Test",
        "linked_products": [  
              {
                "title": "Test",
                "handle": "high-waisted-leggings-3"
              },
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Test",
        "linked_products": [
              {
                "title": "Test",
                "handle": "testb"
              },
        ]
      },
    
      {
        "title": "High waisted leggings",
        "linked_products": [
              {
                "title": "High waisted leggings",
                "handle": "high-waisted-leggings-2"
              },
            
              {
                "title": "High waisted leggings",
                "handle": "high-waisted-leggings"
              }
        ]
      },
    
      {
        "title": "High waisted leggings",
        "linked_products": [
              {
                "title": "High waisted leggings",
                "handle": "high-waisted-leggings-2"
              },
            
              {
                "title": "High waisted leggings",
                "handle": "high-waisted-leggings-1"
              }, 
        ]
      }
    
  ]
}
```

The linked products is indeed right, the comma just isn't working

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to close the `unless` clause on line 15? On line 19 it has an open and closing clause, but not on line 15.

Comment: @BeniTrainor i just fixed that, that was a mistake when I posted here, what is happening is I am looping over all products in collection.products, then in `linked_products` I am looping over them again., so I have a loop in a loop like the first vanilla js example. The forloop object in liquid is having a jumbled index, that's why I can't use `forloop.last`. I'm kind of out of ideas how to fix this

Comment: Have you tried using the [`last`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/last/) filter in your if statements? You could use it to check if an item is not the last one and add the comma accordingly.

Comment: Yes I tried it, I can't use it on the collection, I need to use it on `linked_products` to check if an item is the last one in the `linked_products` array. I don't know how to reference `linked_products` maybe have to use {% assign %}? I usually write vanilla js so this is throwing me for a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your **condition** to add comma is that you never know when the next time the if condition will be true for the related product. So, I have used the [capture tag](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags#capture) to capture the raw string, where a comma is added at the end anytime a related product is found. This condition will always add an additional comma at the end in raw string. Then, you can just remove the last comma before using this raw string in output.
The following code using [remove_last](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters#remove_last) should work fine for your scenario.

```
{
  "title": {{ collection.title | json }},
  "description": {{ collection.description | json }},
  "products": [
    {%- for product in collection.products -%}
        {% capture linked_products_markup %}
            {%- for linked_product in collection.products -%}
                {%- if linked_product.id != product.id and linked_product.title == product.title -%}
                  {
                    "title": {{ linked_product.title | json }},
                    "handle": {{ linked_product.handle | json }}
                  },
                {%- endif -%}
            {%- endfor -%}
        {% endcapture %}
    
      {
        "title": {{ product.title | json }},
        "linked_products": [{{ linked_products_markup | remove_last: ','}}]
      }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless%}
    {%- endfor -%}
  ]
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot! I just started using capture before I read this, I didn't get it to work but I was getting closer, thanks again! That works just like I wanted it to